# vaadin `communication error: check servlets mapping`

Tags: java, servlets, vaadin

I wrote a simple application using vaadin.

```
@Title("PMC")
@Component("pmcVaadin")
@Scope("prototype")
public class PmcUi extends UI {

    @Autowired
    private ContentLayout contentLayout;

    @Autowired
    private TabContent tabs;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        VerticalLayout mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
//        mainLayout.addComponent(contentLayout.getContent());
        mainLayout.addComponent(tabs.createTab("Projects", "Developers"));
        mainLayout.setSizeFull();
        setContent(mainLayout);
    }

}
```

Tabs - my `TabContent` component, extended from `TabSheet`.
But when I click on the tab I've got an error:

`Communication problem Take note of any unsaved data, and click here or press ESC to continue. *UIDL could not be read from server. Check servlets mappings. Error code: 404*`

My `web.xml` looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/pmc-web-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>another-pmc-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.xpoft.vaadin.SpringVaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>beanName</param-name>
            <param-value>pmcVaadin</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>pmc-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>another-pmc-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pmc-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/JSP/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And I get access to the page using URL `http://localhost:8080/pmc-web/VAADIN`.

Comment: Hi Please share the exception you have got in the server logs

Comment: @Patton, I have resolved the problem - I just added mapper for `/*` to my vaadin servlet.

Comment: @user1432980 please create an Answer and mark it as accepted so we know the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve the problem I added mapper for `/*` to vaadin servlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>another-pmc-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```